# NSKeyedArchiver deprecated method problem

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

Just a little background info. I lost my ability to speak a few years ago and learned how to code specifically to make a good text to speech app for myself. Amazingly a lot of others find it useful. Apple reports around 15,000 sessions per week. It is free btw.

At the time I began studying, objective C was the current language so that's what I learned. I am now studying Swift but I am not ready to re write my app. I just don’t know enough yet.

I am trying to update the app but the NSKeyedArchiver has a deprecated method and I'm stuck trying to fix it. Following is a code snippet showing the code. This runs when the user closes the app and it is supposed to save their data:

```
   ...        
    persistence.field19 = [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.autoOn];
   
        persistence.field20 = [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.instructionShown];
        
        NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        //NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    
        NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initRequiringSecureCoding:false];
    
    
        
        [archiver encodeObject:persistence
                        forKey:kDataKey];
        [archiver finishEncoding];
        [data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath]
               atomically:YES];
    }
```

I had the line with the "initForWritingWithMutableData:data" and was told to replace with "initRequiringSecureCoding:Bool". This pleased Xcode removing the warning but the user settings and data are no longer saved. I believe it is because I used to assign the NSMutableData to the archiver but no longer do. I found in the documentation the following that might help but I don’t know how to implement:

```
(NSData *)archivedDataWithRootObject:(id)object 
                 requiringSecureCoding:(BOOL)requiresSecureCoding 
                                 error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

When the app starts up again I load in their settings and saved data with the following:

```
// Restore settings
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingFromData:data error:NULL];
//initForReadingWithData:data];
```

The "initForReadingWithData:data" was also deprecated and I was told to use the "initForReadingFromData:error:" method in its place. I "think" that is fine.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Update: Thanks to TheNextman's suggestion, the archiver is working. This is the current code:

```
    ...
    persistence.field20 = [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.instructionShown];
    
//    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
//    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];

    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initRequiringSecureCoding:false];
    [archiver encodeObject:persistence forKey:kDataKey];
        [archiver finishEncoding];

    NSData* data = [archiver encodedData];
    [data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

    
//    [archiver encodeObject:persistence
//                    forKey:kDataKey];
//    [archiver finishEncoding];
//    [data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath]
//           atomically:YES];
}
```

But for this to work I have to keep using the deprecated unarchiver code.

```
    // Restore settings
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
//        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingFromData:data error:NULL];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
```

The "initForReadingWithData:data" again is deprecated and I'm told to use "initForReadingFromData:error:" If I use the new code, it compiles and runs fine but the user data doesn't reappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't test it, but I think you want the [encodedData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver/1643042-encodeddata?language=objc) property.

> If encoding has not yet finished, invoking this property calls finishEncoding and populates this property with the encoded data

It returns an `NSData` pointer that you can write to disk

```
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initRequiringSecureCoding:false];
[archiver encodeObject:persistence forKey:kDataKey];

NSData* data = [archiver encodedData];
[data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

I then unarchive the object like this:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver* unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingFromData:data error:nil];
[unarchiver setRequiresSecureCoding:NO];
Persistance* p = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:kDataKey];
```

Note that we have to explicitly tell the unarchiver we don't require secure coding (as was specified for the archiver).

If you check the documentation (and indeed, for example the `initForReadingFromData:error:` function above) many of the functions take an optional "error" parameter.

You can pass in a `NSError` pointer and then check what it contains if you don't get your expected result. For example:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver* unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingFromData:data error:nil];
//[unarchiver setRequiresSecureCoding:NO]
NSError* err = nil;
Persistance* p = [unarchiver decodeTopLevelObjectOfClass:[Persistance class] forKey:kDataKey error:&err];
NSLog(@"%@ %@", p, err);
```

In this case, you would have seen the problem:

> (null) Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'Persistance' does not adopt it." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'Persistance' does not adopt it.}

Comment: I am working with your suggestion and am half way there. Can you suggest a change to my NSKeyedUnarchiver code. Because what you suggest for the NSKeyedArchiver works only if I use the deprecated NSKeyedUnarchiver. Does that make sense?